# How to send SMS automatically on mysql Database data change using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sms, sms-gateway

is there any way to send SMS on mysql database data change in PHP?im using twillo as SMS gateway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have control over the PHP code that handles the changes over mysql, you can write your trigger in that code itself, If you only have access the MySQL db not the code that writes to it, you should create a trigger for that particular table, and on change, write some row to another table.

This way you can write a different PHP script that checks the other table in a cronjob for example, and send you an SMS, If some new rows inserted to that table, using Twilio API or another SMS gateway since they do not matter.

See [MySQL Trigger Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) for more information

Comment: No problem R. David. Have a nice day!